# Find the sum of the difference of maximum and minimum element of all subarrays

Tags: stack

sample input: 3 1 4 2

output: 1) Subarrays of size 1 : (3),(1),(4),(2) , sum = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0.

```
    2) Subarrays of size 2: [3, 1], [1, 4], [4, 2], sum = 2 + 3 + 2 = 7.

    3) Subarrays of size 3:- [3, 1, 4], [1, 4, 2], sum = 3 + 3 = 6.
    
    4) Subarrays of size 4:- [3, 1, 4, 2], sum = 3
```

Total sum = 16

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here the problem can solve in many ways, hope this might help you to get your ideas.

```py
arr = [3, 1, 4, 2]
lists = []
res = 0
for i in range(len(arr) + 1):
    for j in range(i):
        if len(arr[j: i]) > 1:
            res += np.max(arr[j:i]) - np.min(arr[j:i])
            lists.append(arr[j:i]) 
print(res)
```

Comment: i want to do this without using lib functions and in time complexity O(n).